# running a Vasp job in HPC cluster

Tags: pyiron

Using pyiron, I build up my script and I would submit it in cluster for running , I was wondering How can I do that ?

Note: Vasp is already installed in my Cluster.

Answer (score 1):

pyiron uses pysqa to submit jobs to a queuing system: 
https://github.com/pyiron/pysqa
With sample queuing configurations available at: 
https://github.com/pyiron/pysqa/tree/master/tests/config
So in your pyiron resources directory you create a folder named `queues` which contains the pysqa queuing system configuration.

Once this is done you can use:

```
job.server.list_queues()
```

to view the available queues and:

```
job.server.view_queues()
```

to get more information about the individual queue and finally submit the job using:

```
job.server.queue = 'queue_name'
```

where `queue_name` is the name of the queue you want to select and then specify the `cores` and `run_time` using:

```
job.server.cores = 8 
job.server.run_time = 30000
```

Finally when you call `job.run()` it is automatically submitted to the queue.

Comment: I couldn't find a public how-to for it, but there is also a job type `ScriptJob` (`pyiron/pyiron/base/job/script.py:ScriptJob`) which allows you to submit an entire notebook to the cluster. Without a tutorial it's probably hard to get going with that from looking at the job type code by itself, but maybe in the future someone can update @Jan's answer with a link to some new documentation.